# How to move copyrights at the end of page in magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to display copyrights under my custom footer

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer"name="footer"template="html/footer_menu.phtml"/>
```

**Edited Question**
***Answer***

```
<move element="copyright" destination="before.body.end"/>
```

Comment: which is your custom footer name?

Comment: "footer" is my custom footer name ...i mentioned in code.

Comment: Got an answer...

Comment: @Ranganathan Can you share the solution.

Comment: I have updated in my question as well